# How can I get products details on CMS Page - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cms, cms-pages

I need to get products `name` and `thumbnail` images on **cms page** if customer enters **sku**, they get `name`, `price`, and `thumbnail` images.

Customer get short details using **sku**, if customer enter sku for given test box, they get short products details like `Name`, `Price`, `Thumbnail`. Is it Codeigniter worth?

Comment: Where the user enters the SKU ?

Comment: Sorry @rathinam, could not understand your question.

Comment: actually need to design text box on custom cms page, when customer enter the sku on the box, they get name, price, thumbnail

Comment: @AmritPalSingh : Text Box on CMS page, when customer enter the sku on text box they get name, price , thumbnail

Comment: @MohitKumarArora : Actully simple text box on my cms page, when user enter the sku or products name, they get name, price, thumbnail

Comment: My need, customer get short details using sku. if customer enter sku for given test box, they get short products details like Name, Price, Thumbnail.   Is it Codeigniter worth?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with jQuery. On entering sku you can call the product collection and show the desired fields in HTML in that CMS page.

You can use this method to call product data:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadBySku($sku);

$_product->getName(); // display product name
```

Comment: How can i use your code on cms block

Comment: its not wokring...

Comment: For this you have to make a custom template .phtml and call it in your cms page.

Comment: I am newbie, could you pls explain briefly.

Comment: I have one Question. Do your CMS page have any other designs or html beside this text box ?

Comment: {{block type="core/template" template="custom/yourfile.phtml"}}. This code is used to call your phtml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59530/discussion-between-rathinam-and-amrit-pal-singh).

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a phtml in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/cms/custom.phtml`

2) Put this piece of code in your cms page:

```
{{ block type="core/template" name="custom.page" template="cms/custom.phtml"}}
```

3) Put your text box and what you want plus the code below in `custom.phtml` "Step 1)"

```
$sku = 10; //this sku you get it from your text box.
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'sku', 'price', 'thumbnail'))
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $sku));

$imageHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
foreach($_product as $prod){
    $name      = $prod->getName();
    $price     = $prod->getPrice();
    $thumbnail = $imageHelper->init($prod, 'thumbnail')->resize(150,220);
}
  echo $name;<br/>

  echo $price;<br/>

  echo $thumbnail;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - just to add to it for others, you could make it more reusable by passing the SKU as a parameter ie `{{ block type="core/template" custom_sku="10" name="custom.page" template="cms/custom.phtml"}}` and retrieve it in the template `$sku = $this->getData('custom_sku');` instead of hardcoding it.